# How is error degrees of freedom (denominator) calculated in mixed model in SPSS?

Tags: spss, mixed-models

In SPSS, I wonder how error degrees of freedom is calculated in a linear mixed model. I have three fixed factors where one is subplot factor (4x3x3). I also included blocking design as random effects (7). I have four different dependent variables. With the exact same model, the df2 (error df) changes when I change the random effects. The error df are also not shown as integer.

So my questions are:

1. How is error df calculated in a linear mixed model in SPSS (in the program)?
2. Why does the error df changes when dependent variable is changed, with exact same model used in linear mixed model in SPSS?

Thank you in advance and please let me know if you need more information about my case,
/Theresa

Answer (score 1):

1. The default (and only, prior to Version 26) method for denominator df calculation in MIXED is Satterthwaite's approximate method, since the precise df aren't generally known for many mixed models. The details on computation are given in the IBM SPSS Statistics Algorithms manual, which is available for download as a pdf. The formulas are not simple though.
2. The approximated df are in part a function of the data values, not just the size of the problem.

Beginning in Version 26, MIXED also supports the residual method and the Kenward-Roger approximation that is considered better in small-sample situations than Satterthwaite's method.